# Exclude locale folders from Carousel

Tags: backup, photos, dropbox

I am using Carousel of Dropbox on my devices.
I would like to exclude some folders from the backup such as screenshot images or whatsapp ones.
I have found something around w.r.t. Google photos app but anything about Carousel.